# PHP/Laravel disappearing variable

Tags: php, laravel

I have some very strange behaviour in an app I am working on. In the example below there are 2 functions.

```
public function updatePhpVhostVersions(Request $r) {
    $data = array(
        'hostname'      => $r['hostname'],
        'username'      => $r['username'],
        'vhost'         => $r['vhost'],
        'php_version'   => $r['php_version']
    );    
    $result = Cpanel::setPhpVhostVersions($data)->data;

    if($r->ajax()){
        return Response::json($result);
    }

    return $result;
}

public function getInstalledPhpVersions(Request $r) {
    $data = array(
        'hostname'  => $r['hostname'],
        'username'  => $r['username']
    );
    $result = Cpanel::getInstalledPhpVersions($data)->data;

    if($r->ajax()){
        return Response::json($result);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The two functions contain `Cpanel:: ... ($data)->data;` this gets handeled by a `__call` method. In this method I use a function that prepares some vars, caching, etc. to simplify things I have combined some functions into one.

```
private function prepare($function, $arguments) {
   // Dettirmine what will be used
   $this->function = $function;
   $nameSplit = preg_split('/(?=\p{Lu})/u', $function);
   $this->class = 'App\\Phase\\Cpanel\\' . $this->folder($nameSplit) . '\\' . $this->file($nameSplit);

   // Cache True/False
   if(isset($this->arguments['cache'])) {   
       $this->cache = $this->arguments['cache'];
   }

   // Get the provided arguments
   // these are used in the API post 
   if(isset($arguments[0]['hostname'], $arguments[0]['username'])) {
       $arguments = $arguments[0];
   }  
   $this->arguments = $arguments;

    // Flush the cache when needed
    if (!$this->cache || in_array($nameSplit[0], array('create', 'delete', 'add', 'install', 'set'))) {
        try {
            Cache::tags(['cpanel', $this->function . $arguments['username']])
                    ->flush();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
                dd($arguments);
        }   
    }
}
```

The `prepare` method is used every time the `__call` method gets used. In `Cpanel::setPhpVhostVersion()` the `$arguments` somehow get empty after the following if statement.

```
// Flush the cache when needed
if (!$this->cache || in_array($nameSplit[0], array('create', 'delete', 'add', 'install', 'set'))) {
    try {
        Cache::tags(['cpanel', $this->function . $arguments['username']])
            ->flush();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        dd($e);
    }   
}
```

Before `Cache::tags()` the `$arguments` contains an array with some user information. But when `Cache::tags()->flush()` gets called it throws an exception that `$arguments['username']` is empty. Now if I `dd($arguments)` after this, it returns an empty array. If I `dd()` before this the array still has the information. This only happens with `Cpanel::setPhpVhostVersion()` not with the 37 other possible `Cpanel:: ... ()` what could be causing this?

**EDIT**

After some playing around with the code, I noticed that `$arguments` gets empty everytime after it gets used. It does not matter where, it just gets empty. (But only with `setPhpVhostVersions`)

**Example**

```
if(!isset($this->arguments['username'])) {
    return Api::respondUnauthenticated('Account username is a required parameter');
}
```

Before the `!isset()` the `$arguments['username']` exists, during and after the `!isset()` I get the exception:

> ErrorException: Undefined index: username

Comment: So, where do you expect us to find code for `setPhpVhostVersion`?

Comment: The code for setPhpVhostVErsion is not included because this function's logic is only called after this prepare function and after some other validations  The $arguments array gets empty after the cache flush, and if I remove the flush, the $arguments gets empty the next time the array is used. I know this is a vague question, I can not explain it better because this does not make any sense... I will try to improve the question.